# T-SQL vs Sybase SELECT with AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, alias, sybase

In Sybase is it possible to do such T-SQL `SELECT`s:

```
SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B, A+B AS C
```

Under MS SQL Server (doesn't matter which version) I got an error like:

> Meldung 207, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 9
> Ungültiger Spaltenname "A".
> Meldung 207, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 9
> Ungültiger Spaltenname "B".*

But I can do SELECTs like

```
SELECT field AS a FROM table
ORDER BY a
```

Is there a possibility under SQL Server to use the same syntax as Sybase?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Also, *all* content on [so] needs to be in English. An error in a different language is not helpful; you should take the time to translate it or get the English error from the system.

Comment: For more information, see [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: What you ask is a Sybase quirk. No other database allows this as far as I know. If you use eg dbFiddle you'll see that the query fails in MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite as well. *All* database products have quirks and custom extensions to SQL.

Comment: You can do `select x.*, A+B as C from (SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B) x`.

Comment: DuckDB also allows this as one of its many syntax extensions https://duckdb.org/2023/08/23/even-friendlier-sql.html